# Notepad++ - make functions "clickable"?

Tags: windows, notepad++, editing

I just thought about this maybe being useful, but I can't find a way to do it.

Is there a way, in Notepad++, to make function names "clickable" -- ie make them links, so that if you click on them, it automatically takes you to its definition (ideally across an entire code-base)?

Comment: Now there is a way! See the changelog snippet below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there's no plugin offering directly clickable function names.
But you could try the plugin SourceCookifier together with some N++ tweaking.
Open N++'s "contextMenu.xml" and add this line somewhere:

```
<Item PluginEntryName="SourceCookifier" PluginCommandItemName="Go To Definition"/>
```

At least a solution to have it with 2 mouse clicks > right click > contextmenu > "Go To Definition".
I would rather say simply press CTRL + SHIFT + RETURN when the cursor is on a symbol, which also executes
"Go To Definition", but since you asked for a mouse button approach..

/EDIT

There has been an update of the plug-in these days.
Here's a snippet from the changelog:

**0.7.1**

*-new: option "Go to definition by pressing **ctrl + left mousebutton**"*

Comment: Can confirm the plugin still works well as of Jan. 2015. Neat find.

Comment: @Mahn you don't need a plugin to use this feature, just ctrl+click and it works