# Goto definition like feature in custom (user-defined) language in notepad++

Tags: tags, notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, ctags

Is there any way (by means of plugins or settings) to create (by that I mean modifying, adding & deleting) custom tags in notepad++?
By tags I mean, to jump to the definition of an instance used anywhere in project (some kind of like 'goto definition' function like we have in other popular languages like C, C++, C#).
I searched for this topic but could not find satisfactory result.

**My requirement:**
I have created a custom language in Notepad++ (by adding keywords, coloring patterns and other rules). Now I need the way to add custom tags for this language. How can I achieve this?
With the help of tags I should be able to navigate to definition (just like goto definition in other popular languages) in the particular project (all files in project or at least opened files).

Comment: It is not clear from your question if notepad++ has a custom tag function that you are asking about, or if it just uses ctags and you want to know how to generate a normal ctags file.

Comment: I don't know what "ctags" does (I beleive it only generates tags for header files), my question is how can I navigate to any variable's definition in my custom language?
For eg; In my custom language, variable def is:
`VARIABLE some_variable_name` **this is my area of interest to navigate to from anywhere in my project**
`{`
`  //contents in this  variable`
`}`
so whenever I click (or execute) "goto definition" on _some_variable_name_, it should jump (take me to) to its def as above.

hope this will explain my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had to deal with essentially the same issue. I am using Notepad++ with a legacy codebase written in a custom markup language. Each file can contain cross references to definitions in other files, so a way of jumping to the definition would be very useful.

It has not been easy to find a solution that meets all four requirements: **a goto definiton feature** that works across **multiple files** and for a **custom language** in **Notepad++**. I found this question while searching for a solution; the answer jussij provided is good but it does not really provide a complete solution.

I ended up using the [SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/) plugin with a custom language definition. There is not a huge amount of guidance online about how to use it, but once installed you can use it to manually create a language definition using regex rules.

SourceCookifier will work for your language if you can configure the following:

- A set of file extensions used by the language
- A set of tag types (i.e. a function, class, variable)
- A set of POSIX Basic Regular Expressions for locating each tag type, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115333/add-rule-to-sourcecookifier-plugin-for-notepad)

Once a language has been defined, you can highlight any instance of a found tag and use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Enter to jump to the definition of that tag. This can work across a whole codebase of files if you provide it with a list of files to inspect, it calls this a 'session'. All you need to do is drag and drop your codebase folder into the SourceCookifier sidebar window. The codebase I was working with is very large, so I am only using basic functionality, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549752/notepad-sourcecookifier-plugin-very-slow-on-large-c-headers) for a good explination of that. The goto definition shortcut can also be added to a right-click context menu, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890845/notepad-make-functions-clickable).

Comment: Thanks! Actually jussij's answer led me to SourceCookifier plug-in (which in-turn is based on Exuberant Ctags) so I don't have any complain about it. Few interesting things I noticed about SourceCookifier are - **1-** You can use it with your project (how long it maybe it does not matter), all you have to do is to increase your symbols buffer and include files size. You can do it in _SourceCookifier>Options_ in the open panel increase the number of symbols to show (default is 2048). You may also need to increase the INCLUDE files size based on your project.**see 2nd pt in nxt comment**

Comment: **The above comment is continued here, as I used up the space allowed for a comment.** **2-** 'Cookie Session' is good but not full fledged. It does not updates when any new symbol is added (we have to **REFRESH** it every time in order to update the tags and jump to correct source). And second thing is, if we reopen the Notepad++, the last cookie session used is **NOT** loaded on its own. These two points frustrates me many times as updating tags take some time (depending on your files) and NPP freezes until its done. Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for following up on what you ended up doing! I have not looked at the options page much, but I really should as my project could well be maxing out the limit. I agree with your comment about refresing, while tweaking with the language settings I found that I had to rebuild the session a few times to get it to working. _-cont-_

Comment: By accident I found a very useful way you can mis-use the plugin: The regexs I used ended up matching the definition and uses/instances of the tags I was interested in. To begin with I was irritated by this, but actually it is great because the tool gives you a drop down menu to select the correct 'definition' from all the matches it has found. This essentailly has made it into a **find all references** search rather than a **goto definition** shortcut, which is actually more useful for my situation (I am only using the basic INCLUDE mode for all files).

Answer (score 3):

> Now I need the way to add custom tags for this language. How can I achieve this?

If you're using [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) you can configure a new language definition using just a handful of regular expressions.

For example [this link](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?t=3367) shows how to configure ctags for the *Clipper* language using this regexp approach:

Comment: @jussigj - Thanks !! I have downloaded "Exuberant Ctags" zip folder and extracted it to *Notepad++\plugins* folder on my computer, but it does not appear in my Notepad++'s plugins list. Could you please suggest what is happing wrong here. I also found out that, to use it with Notepad++ it has to used with other programs such as, OpenCtags or Source Cookifier. Is it the case? I tried with "OpenCtags" but I was not able to configure it. Can you please suggest how can I create custom language Ctags file.

Comment: The "Exuberant Ctags" zip will contain a ctags.exe file. I am not familiar with how Notepad++ ctags plug-ins work but the ctags.exe should just replace the ctags exe that you have. You ask *Can you please suggest how can I create custom*. Refer to the link in my post. That shows how to define a new Clipper langauge. Just change it to match you language. Once you have defined your language just run the ctags.exe from the command line and check tags file that gets produced.

Comment: Well, no problems and thanks for introducing me to the procedure using which I can create custom Ctags..It's helpful for me to keep moving, I appreciate that..I will find some way to access the custom tags from Notepad++.